# Insert Cms Block After end page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am new to magento.I have created a CMS page with 2 column right layout and showing some static text and images in left and products in right. but we need to add a static block after right and left column.

I want to add this using xml update layout .please help.any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

goto your admin>CMS>Page click on your cms page  design tab

and add the below code

```
<reference name="root">
  <block type="cms/block" name="aminmycallout" after="footer">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your-block</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

add then below to 
`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('aminmycallout') ?>` before `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>`

Comment: My dear this will add in left or right column .I need to add new cms block below the left and right column and above the footer column.please help.